# jQuery setTimeout reset?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a few divs that display different images when clicked and then fade back after 5 seconds. Only I want this number to get reset each time a div is clicked. Below is the code I've tried to use, but it doesn't work.

```
var showServicesDelay = function() {
            timeoutHandle = setTimeout(function () {
                    jQuery(".services-inner").css({"opacity": "0.5"});
                jQuery(".insignia-inner").css({"opacity": "1"});
                jQuery(".insignia-inner-text").css({"opacity": "1"});
                hideAll();
        }, 5000);       
    };

    var showMilitaryKit = function() {
        jQuery(".military-kit-inner").css({"opacity": "1"});

        clearTimeout(timeoutHandle);
};

var showProperty = function() {
        jQuery(".property-inner").css({"opacity": "1"});

        clearTimeout(timeoutHandle);    
};

var showHomeContents = function() {
        jQuery(".home-contents-inner").css({"opacity": "1"});

        clearTimeout(timeoutHandle);
};

// military kit
    jQuery(".military-kit-hover").click(function() {        
        hideAll();
        hideServices();
        showMilitaryKit();
        showServicesDelay();
    });

// property
    jQuery(".property-hover").click(function() {
        hideAll();
        hideServices();
        showProperty();
        showServicesDelay();
    }); 

// home contents
    jQuery(".home-contents-hover").click(function() {
        hideAll();
        hideServices();
        showHomeContents();
        showServicesDelay();
    });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are nullifying your handle to the setTimeout before you call `clearTimeout`:

```
timeoutHandle = null;   
clearTimeout(timeoutHandle);
```

Should just be:

```
clearTimeout(timeoutHandle);
```